# Laravel Scraping website give me empty list

Tags: php, laravel, web-scraping

I want to scrape my own livescore website but I have recieved empty result.

I created this controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Goutte\Client;

class MainController extends Controller
{

    public function livescore()
    {
        $url = 'https:/xxxxxxxxxxx/';
        $result = array();
        $client = new Client();
        $page = $client->request(
            'GET',
            $url
        );
        try {
           $page->filter('.event__match event__match--twoLine > div')->each(function($data){
               $result[]=$data->flter('.event__participant event__participant--home')->text();
           });
           dd($result);
        } catch (\Throwable $err) {
            dd($err);
        }  
    }
}
```

The inspect html is like this
[image]

How can I do it?

Comment: Is the app you are trying to scrape a Single Page Application that requires JavaScript? Is the same source code shown when you view page source(`ctrl+u`)?

Comment: @MaartenDev yes it is SPA

Comment: Goutte doesn't support Javascript and thus cannot render the contents of the website that you are trying to parse. You will need to use a headless browser like Puppeteer, Cypress or phantomjs that supports JavaScript to retrieve the website content.

Comment: An alternative would be to check which AJAX calls are being made with javascript by the SPA and try to use those to get your data. Keep in mind that it might be a private API